# AH00961 Proxy redirect

Tags: node.js, apache, virtual, host

I'm trying to redirect my node.js app which is using port 9025 to port 80 and 443 using Apache's Proxy Redirect, but when I reload apache I get this:

`[Sun Dec 17 18:18:08.235231 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 20851] [remote VPSip:9025] AH01961: SSL Proxy requested for VPSIp:80 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]

[Sun Dec 17 18:18:08.235297 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 20851] AH00961: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for VPSIp:9025 (VPSIp)`

And yes, I have enabled SSLProxyEngine on the VirtualHost's config.

Comment: Can you show us your config? It might be an issue with SSLProxyEngine being declared in the wrong place.

Comment: Config file: https://gist.github.com/ArtutoGamer/bdc0d109feceb32770d8ee4031a15f83